# Update MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a page that I can update through a form and mysql php. I updated the db call from `require "master.db.php";` to `require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/master.db.php';`

I get a "successfully updated" message when I process a form update but when the page reloads the updates are not present. No error is being thrown so its unclear why the database is not taking the update. Checked MySql db using phpMyAdmin and was able to update the db directly with no trouble?

I am at a total loss because this problem is only effecting 'updating' and 'deleting'. I have an 'add entry' form that works correctly and its db call code is the same as the others. I have already tried rolling back to my old code but the problem is still present. Tried restarting browser and clearing cash. Any advise?

```
<?php
// connect to datebase
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/master.db.php';
// real escape all strings
$season_num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['season_num']);
$eps_num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['eps_num']);
$temp_eps_num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['temp_eps_num']);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$inspired = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inspired']);
$descrip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descrip']);

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE season SET season_num='$season_num', eps_num='$eps_num', temp_eps_num='$temp_eps_num', title='$title', inspired='$inspired', descrip='$descrip' WHERE ID='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='example.html'>View result</a>";
touch('../example.html');
clearstatcache();
}

else {
echo "Whoops: " . mysql_error(); ;
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: If the changes are committed in the database but your browser isn't showing them, then it's either the code that is fetching the data or your browser is caching the page.

Comment: thats the problem, the db is not getting the changes. When I look at the db in phpmyadmin I do not see any of my updates yet I get no errors and a "successfully updated" statement.
I tried to add
// if successfully updated.
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "Updated: " . $result . "<BR>";
echo "<a href='../episodelist_superadmin.html'>View result</a>";
touch('../episodelist.html');
clearstatcache();
}
to see what was being passed to the server and all it spit out was the number "1" next to "Updated:"

Comment: Add `or die(mysql_error());` after `mysql_query`.

Comment: like this `$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: still getting a "Successful Updated: 1" ??

Comment: Are your errors being suppressed? Make sure your `error_reporting` is disabled. Are you sure you're updating the right database?

Comment: Yes, I have checked master.db.php. I am connecting and trying to update the correct db. I edited master.db.php to deliberately throw an error and errors are being reported. Im still perplexed?

Comment: How about you `echo $sql;` before you submit it?

Comment: I just retested my 'add new' form and its working and adding to the same db. all running off of master.db.php so that cant be the problem? Ill try the `echo $sql;`

Comment: `echo $sql;` spit out
UPDATE season SET season_num='1', eps_num='45', temp_eps_num='54', title='Another Test', inspired='Idk', descrip='No this will work' WHERE ID=''View result

Comment: I saw that, the update form page is pulling the ID in and passing it half way thought the update process so, what or where am i missing code?

Comment: **How** is the code being pulled in? `GET`, `POST`?

Comment: The edit form has a url of `edit.html?id=55` I must have deleted a string of code that pulls in the id?

Comment: // Get ID
   $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

Comment: Then you just answered your own question.

Comment: the form has a `<input type="hidden" name="id" size="50" value="<?php echo($fields['id']); ?>">`

Comment: So again, you're not retrieving that in the code above.

Comment: adding `$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);` solved my problem. Thanks njk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);` solved my problem. Thanks njk